# Can I have two different font sizes in a matplotlib axes label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Is is possible to have two different font sizes in one matplotlib axes label?
I know I can set the font size with

`fontsize = int`

but what I would like to do is something like:

```
plt.ylabel('Text 1', fontsize1=20, 'Text 2', fontsize2=15)
```

is there a way in matplotlib / seaborn to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is using LaTeX in order to get different sizes in the same string:

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.ylabel(r'\small{Text 1} \Huge{Text2}')
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! But it somehow doesn't like my title anymore and throws  1.5 pages of error.. well, you can't have everything!

Comment: @ Jaume : LaTeX...latex was not able to process the following string:
'+++Other normalization ---Correlation KD - GC content - replicates removed(mean of mean) cost_fix<50+++' which was the title of my plot having (in my opinion) nothing to do with latex

Comment: @MaxS, you are right, this string can not be processed as string by LaTeX, but it is due to some special characters that LaTeX interprets as mathematical symbols. Then, the error you get is "please, user, use the math environment to use these symbols". In your specific case, is the down slash "_". Put a backslash "\" in front of it and it's all. Be careful with these special characters